# how to filter out entries of set

Tags: javascript

for the following contents of `data` object:

```
0
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'FAUSY', crop: 'Rotbuche'}
1
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PSTME', crop: 'Douglasie'}
2
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'QUESS', crop: 'Eiche'}
3
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'YLAGL', crop: 'Langholzpolter'}
4
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PIEPU', crop: 'Blaufichte'}
5
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'ALUSS', crop: 'Erle'}
6
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'POPSS', crop: 'Pappel'}
7
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'YLAGE', crop: 'Einzelstämme'}
8
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'NNNZG', crop: 'Ziergehölze'}
9
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'ACRCA', crop: 'Acer campestre'}
10
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'YLAGS', crop: 'Schichtholzpolter'}
11
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PIUSS', crop: 'Kiefer'}
12
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'ABINO', crop: 'Nordmann-Tanne'}
13
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'CIPBE', crop: 'Carpinus betulus'}
14
: 
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'LAXSS', crop: 'Lärche'}
```

i want to filter out the contents of the object `data` by the `crop` name `Eiche` and `Kiefer`
i want to make `data` contains only the 2nd and the 11th entries. in other words, i want `data` to contain:

```
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'QUESS', crop: 'Eiche'}
{pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PIUSS', crop: 'Kiefer'}
```

how can i achieve that please

Comment: @cmgchess it is an object

Comment: whats the final output structure. object or array?

Comment: @cmgchess i slightly added some more text to the question, please have a look

Comment: @cmgchess i expect the output to be an object as well, as mentioned in the question

Comment: https://codeshare.io/8p0xZj , https://codeshare.io/j0qlvB many ways to do this actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Set` to filter the needed crops:

```js
const data = [
  { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'FAUSY', crop: 'Rotbuche' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PSTME', crop: 'Douglasie' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'QUESS', crop: 'Eiche' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'YLAGL', crop: 'Langholzpolter' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PIEPU', crop: 'Blaufichte' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'ALUSS', crop: 'Erle' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'POPSS', crop: 'Pappel' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'YLAGE', crop: 'Einzelstämme' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'NNNZG', crop: 'Ziergehölze' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'ACRCA', crop: 'Acer campestre' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'YLAGS', crop: 'Schichtholzpolter' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PIUSS', crop: 'Kiefer' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'ABINO', crop: 'Nordmann-Tanne' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'CIPBE', crop: 'Carpinus betulus' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'LAXSS', crop: 'Lärche' },
];

const filter = new Set( ['Eiche' , 'Kiefer']);
const filteredArray = data.filter(({crop}) => filter.has(crop));


console.log(filteredArray);
```

An one-liner:

```js
const data = [
  { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'FAUSY', crop: 'Rotbuche' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PSTME', crop: 'Douglasie' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'QUESS', crop: 'Eiche' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'YLAGL', crop: 'Langholzpolter' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PIEPU', crop: 'Blaufichte' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'ALUSS', crop: 'Erle' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'POPSS', crop: 'Pappel' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'YLAGE', crop: 'Einzelstämme' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'NNNZG', crop: 'Ziergehölze' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'ACRCA', crop: 'Acer campestre' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'YLAGS', crop: 'Schichtholzpolter' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'PIUSS', crop: 'Kiefer' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'ABINO', crop: 'Nordmann-Tanne' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'CIPBE', crop: 'Carpinus betulus' },
   { pppId: '005618-00', eppo: 'LAXSS', crop: 'Lärche' },
];

const filteredArray = data.reduce((r, item) => (r.set.has(item.crop) && r.arr.push(item), r), {set: new Set( ['Eiche' , 'Kiefer']), arr:[]}).arr;


console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'FAUSY',
    crop: 'Rotbuche'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'PSTME',
    crop: 'Douglasie'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'QUESS',
    crop: 'Eiche'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'YLAGL',
    crop: 'Langholzpolter'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'PIEPU',
    crop: 'Blaufichte'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'ALUSS',
    crop: 'Erle'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'POPSS',
    crop: 'Pappel'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'YLAGE',
    crop: 'Einzelstämme'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'NNNZG',
    crop: 'Ziergehölze'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'ACRCA',
    crop: 'Acer campestre'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'YLAGS',
    crop: 'Schichtholzpolter'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'PIUSS',
    crop: 'Kiefer'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'ABINO',
    crop: 'Nordmann-Tanne'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'CIPBE',
    crop: 'Carpinus betulus'
  },
  {
    pppId: '005618-00',
    eppo: 'LAXSS',
    crop: 'Lärche'
  },
];


let filter = data.filter((data) => data.crop == 'Eiche' || data.crop == 'Kiefer');
console.log(filter);
```